# How to retrieve date field from SQL in C++

Tags: c++, sql, date

Using Microsoft Access, I have a field with a `Date/Time` data type. I want to load this into my C++ program, but I don't know what the integral datatype that `Date/Time` is. Here is the code that I use to retrieve it,

```
const char* qry = "SELECT * FROM TBL";

//Query data
m_ReturnStatus = SQLAllocStmt(m_Connection, &m_QueryStatement);
m_ReturnStatus = SQLPrepare(m_QueryStatement, (SQLCHAR*)qry, SQL_NTS);

/* Excecute the query */
m_ReturnStatus = SQLExecute(Get_Instance().m_QueryStatement);
m_ReturnStatus = SQLFetch(Get_Instance().m_QueryStatement);
while (SQL_SUCCEEDED(Get_Instance().m_ReturnStatus))
{    
    unsigned long date; //or char date[11] 
    m_ReturnStatus = SQLGetData(m_QueryStatement, 1, SQL_C_ULONG, &date, 1, nullptr);
    m_ReturnStatus = SQLFetch(m_QueryStatement); //returns next rowset
    std::cout << date << std::endl;
};
m_ReturnStatus = SQLFreeStmt(m_QueryStatement, SQL_DROP);
```

in this example, the database would just be

```
TableDate

12/03/2021
12/03/2021
.
.
.
```

Using `date` as an `unsigned long`, the output for `12/03/2021` is `1044`. Using `date` as `char [11]` with `SQLGetData(m_QueryStatement, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, date, 11, nullptr);`, the output is unexpected. The first console output is `(]ù`, followed by an endless stream of `╨☻`, which seems odd because the actual date value does not change.

Also noting that in Access, there is a `DateValue` function used to insert dates into the table, and the returned value of `12/03/2021` is `44267`.

Comment: Some microsoft info claims: `Access stores the Date/Time data type as a double-precision, floating-point number up to 15 decimal places. The integer part of the double-precision number represents the date. The decimal portion represents the time.` Found that information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/store-calculate-compare-datetime-data)

Comment: @PaulT. I saw that, however I also tried a double type, same result as Unsigned long.

Comment: The date looks like December 3rd to me but it could be March 12th to you, so if March 12th is true, then the value of 44267 is correct for the number of days since December 30th 1899. The example table dates do not have a time portion, so I guess that part is okay as not needed?

Comment: @PaulT. The `44267` was demonstrating the correct result, I am getting `1044` instead.

Comment: Oh, apologies on that, misread. I'm sure that you may have already tried, but what did you get using `SQL_C_DOUBLE`?

Comment: `1044` as well.